# How to load Prolog files

Tags: prolog

How do I load files into Prolog? I type in the filename followed by a . but I get an error. Maybe I have to tell Prolog where to look, but am unsure on how to tell it?

Comment: Suggestion by user1892991 should work. You must post some other info to get some help...

Comment: You should read some of the introductory material in the documentation that comes with your specific Prolog interpreter. This information is covered there.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what exactly error message you got, but from "Maybe I have to tell Prolog where to look" I assume you got something like "file not found".

Let's suppose you use a Windows operating system and you have a file named 'file1.pl' in the directory "C:\Users\Name\Prolog\".

Then you can use following commands in Prolog to consult your file (note forward, not back, slashes):

```
cd('C:/Users/Name/Prolog').
['file1.pl'].
```

Adjust the commands to your path and file names.

Comment: Are you assuming SWI Prolog (with the use of `cd/1`)? OP didn't specify.

Comment: @lurker Yes, I'm assuming SWI. But B-Prolog and ECLiPSe also have `cd/1`.